# Problems converting collection types from scala to java

Tags: java, scala, cassandra, hector

I am using the hector HOM library to access my cassandra datastore.  This library is written in java and uses some reflexion when working with Collections.

I have a java Model that contains a List of Strings that I want to retrieve.  Unfortunately I get the following exception:

```
Execution exception [[HectorObjectMapperException: exception while instantiating Collection type, scala.collection.JavaConversions$SeqWrapper]]

Caused by: me.prettyprint.hom.cache.HectorObjectMapperException: exception while instantiating Collection type, scala.collection.JavaConversions$SeqWrapper
    at me.prettyprint.hom.CollectionMapperHelper.instantiateCollection(CollectionMapperHelper.java:87) ~[hector-object-mapper-3.0-02.jar:na]
    at me.prettyprint.hom.HectorObjectMapper.createObject(HectorObjectMapper.java:297) ~[hector-object-mapper-3.0-02.jar:na]
    at me.prettyprint.hom.HectorObjectMapper.getObject(HectorObjectMapper.java:105) ~[hector-object-mapper-3.0-02.jar:na]
    at me.prettyprint.hom.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:132) ~[hector-object-mapper-3.0-02.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: scala.collection.JavaConversions$SeqWrapper
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at me.prettyprint.hom.CollectionMapperHelper.instantiateCollection(CollectionMapperHelper.java:75) ~[hector-object-mapper-3.0-02.jar:na]
    at me.prettyprint.hom.HectorObjectMapper.createObject(HectorObjectMapper.java:297) ~[hector-object-mapper-3.0-02.jar:na]
```

I have tried explicitly creating a java.util.list object but it still causes the same problems. Here is my code to create and persist my model:

```
val geoModel = new GeoModel(geoRK)
val thingList: java.util.List[java.lang.String] = things match {
  case Some(t) => t.map(s => s.toString())
  case None => new java.util.ArrayList()
}
geoModel.setThings(thingList)
geoDAO.upsertModel(geoModel)
```

The model persists fine and I can see it in cassandra as:

```
(column=things, value=scala.collection.JavaConversions$SeqWrapper:0, timestamp=1333555422145002)
```

The problem is when retrieving the object back it appears Hector doens't know how to handle the scala.collection type.

Is there anyway to get around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:

Sorry... misleading toString impl of scala.collection.JavaConversions$SeqWrapper it returns the same...

You could however create a java.util.List from your List yourself as a workaround.

original:

instead of collection.JavaConversion you could use collections.JavaConverters.

```
scala> import collection.JavaConverters._
import collection.JavaConverters._

scala> List(1,2,3).asJava
res1: java.util.List[Int] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually got around it by initializing my list as a java.util.ArrayList[String] instead of letting the map function create the new list:

```
val thingList = new java.util.ArrayList[String]
things match {
  case Some(t) => t.map(s => thingList.add(s))
  case None => new java.util.ArrayList()
}
```

Comment: You should use `foreach` instead of `map` if you don't use the result of the `map`.